# cURL call in AngularJS using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, curl

I am new to angular and I'm trying to pass an access token in my header, but I cant seem to get it right.

I have a curl request that works fine and I'm trying to get it in working in angular:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users -IH "Authorization: Token api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Angular $http call that isn't working

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users', {headers: {'api_key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}}).then(function(response) {
                service.currentUser = response.data.user;
                console.log(service.currentUser);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your curl I think the request should look like:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users', 
    {headers: { Authorization: ' Token api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}})
    .then(function(response) {
            service.currentUser = response.data.user;
            console.log(service.currentUser);
    });
```

Comment: Yes, surprised I missed that. Thanks!